# PyQt5 - cannot resolve a dialog's slot

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to port a small Qt C++ app to Python using PyQt5 but I am having trouble with the most basic stuff right now.
I've used the pyuic utility to transform a .ui file to its corresponding .py file representing the dialog's statically defined UI and exactly two signal/slot pairs (two buttons). The exact error is "'QDialog' object has no attribute 'pushButtonStartClick'" and while I understand what it is describing I don't know how exactly to fix it. I'm not even sure custom slots can be defined in the Ui class. If that is true, it represents a pretty huge limitation. I'm using PyQt 5.4 and Python 2.7 on a Windows machine.

Additional info - simple [tutorial](http://projects.skylogic.ca/blog/how-to-install-pyqt5-and-build-your-first-gui-in-python-3-4/) I've been reading and trying to emulate.

Thank you in advance.

Generated .py file containing the UI class (part of it, source .ui file is [here](http://pastebin.com/1vL2psZG)):

```
class Ui_NewGameDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, NewGameDialog):
        NewGameDialog.setObjectName("NewGameDialog")
        NewGameDialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        NewGameDialog.resize(265, 200)
        #
        # ...
        #
        self.retranslateUi(NewGameDialog)
        # part where it breaks apart
        self.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(NewGameDialog.pushButtonStartClick)
        self.pushButtonCancel.clicked.connect(NewGameDialog.pushButtonCancelClick)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NewGameDialog)
```

Class that inherits it:

```
class NewGameDialog(Ui_NewGameDialog):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_NewGameDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setFixedSize(dialog.size())
        dialog.setWindowFlags(
                dialog.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
        )

    @pyqtSlot(name="pushButtonStartClick")
    def pushButtonStartClick(self):
        pass

    @pyqtSlot(name="pushButtonCancelClick")
    def pushButtonCancelClick(self):
        pass
```

Initialization:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = NewGameDialog(dialog)
    dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You cannot refer to `NewGameDialog` in `Ui_NewGameDialog` since it practically does not exist in that context.

Comment: I am aware, I just don't know how this is normally done. Signals and slots can be defined in the .ui file just fine (works in a C++ environment). The complete file is now on Pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setupUi method was getting a wrong kind of object, since QDialog doesn't have those `pushButtonStartClick` and `pushButtonCancelClick`.

```py
class NewGameDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_NewGameDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        Ui_NewGameDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowFlags(
            self.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
        )

    @pyqtSlot(name="pushButtonStartClick")
    def pushButtonStartClick(self):
        pass

    @pyqtSlot(name="pushButtonCancelClick")
    def pushButtonCancelClick(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    dialog = NewGameDialog()
    dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Without multiple inheritance:

```
class NewGameDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewGameDialog, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_NewGameDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = NewGameDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar, but can it be put in the .ui file itself? I have a few of those and it would require some work that I think is basically unnecessary. On a side note, isn't that how it is done in PyQt4?

Comment: I think I was giving a wrong answer, I'll try to correct soon

Comment: Thank you, it works just fine now (quite elegant, too). It would be impossible without multiple inheritance, though. I'll up-vote your answer but wait a few hours to see if someone else comes up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @JJHakala (that uses multiple inheritance) is option 3 in the [PyQt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Option 2 also suits your situation (this is a slightly more elegant version of the "without multiple inheritance" option presented in J. J. Hakala's edit, based on the example in the PyQt docs):

```
class NewGameDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_NewGameDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowFlags(
                self.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
        )

    @pyqtSlot(name="pushButtonStartClick")
    def pushButtonStartClick(self):
        pass

    @pyqtSlot(name="pushButtonCancelClick")
    def pushButtonCancelClick(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    dialog = NewGameDialog()
    dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, both approaches describe exactly what I wanted to achieve. I'll accept the other answer because @J. J. Hakala was faster, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Venom Nope, I don't mind. they've update their answer to use the more elegant method anyway (it basically means your widget is more reusable as you only need one line of code to instantiate the widget) so my answer is superfluous.